# Using a table view for entering data

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios4

With the regular table view touching a table cell will switch to another view. I have seen some applications that are using something that looks similar to a table view except touching a cell brings up the keyboard so that text can be entered into the cell. It looks kind of like a table view, but a little different. What are they using to make these tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a table view all right. The cells contain `UITextField`s or `UITextView`s, usually of the borderless variant to make them fade into the surrounding cell.